# SQL Server Date format difference

Tags: sql-server, date

I have set a SQl Server DB to British English. I ran the following to check that it was British English and it is

```
select name ,alias, dateformat
from syslanguages
where langid =
(
    select value from master..sysconfigures
    where comment = 'default language'
);
```

yet in the tables the date is displayed as international Date and time.

Background: I migrated the tables from an Access DB into SQL Server. I have not run any code to change how the dates are displayed in the table other than to change the language.

thanks
maggs

Comment: Dates are not stored in any format; display is determined by the tool handling the display. I think you *want* and should *prefer* an unambiguous, clear, international format, you just don't realize it yet.

Comment: You need to tell us: what datatype are these 'dates' stored in? are they a proper date data type (DATE or DATETIME) or are they some kind of character storage (VARCHAR etc.)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server stores datetime internally as an 8-byte field.  No matter what the DB language/date format is, the internal storage remains the same.  All your language settings do is alter the default way a datetime is shown as a string e.g. in SSMS when you select datetime columns

You can control the appearance of datetime using CAST AND CONVERT  numeric options e.g. 120
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 120) 
See CAST and CONVERT in Books Online for all the other options

Also check the column type your Access tables were imported to.  Its all to easy to get everything to import as nvarchar(255) when accepting the defaults.